# Closing and Downvoting questions on facebook.stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

I [asked a question on the 'new' Facebook Stack Overflow](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7270992/posting-a-link-to-a-fan-page-through-an-application), and feel this is very developer related - I am having an issue posting to a Facebook page with code that used to work. So if I had left out more information - and just asked 'how do I do this', would that be more valid?

This may confuse users, because in their forums, users could ask questions about their code and get responses. And even with Stack Overflow, its common to ask a question about why code doesnt work. By adding more information - that I have code that worked but now doesn't - it makes my valid question - how to post to a page wall - look like its not technically related.

I can only guess that this question got downvoted and voted to close because its asking why something on Facebook's end that used to work no longer does - in which I created a bug in their issue tracker.

It seems that many people may run into this issue - getting downvoted for very valid questions on the old FB platform and SO, and scare users from posting.

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: Unfortunately, facebook.SO is getting *slammed* with awful NPR questions, so people following that godawful tag are going to be very jumpy and fast to react and close anything that smells rotten.

Comment: Trust me, nobody has seemed scared to post a FB question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

That looks like a valid question to me.  It may seem borderline to some though, since the [Facebook Developer Support](https://developers.facebook.com/support/) page does say:

> The Facebook Platform bug tracking system is where you go to report an issue with a legitimate repro.

I don't see anything wrong with asking on Stack Overflow first though, since here you may get help either 1) coming up with an alternate solution, or 2) verifying that it *is* a bug that you need to report to Facebook.

Comment: I have done both. I reported it as a bug to them, but its also a valid question in how to do this. I may edit the question more to ask more on 'how to do this' than 'whats wrong with this'.

Comment: @jmlumpkin: That sounds like a good idea.  You might also want to stress that you already reported a bug to Facebook.